# Calling a CSS animation using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, function, animation

I'm having a little trouble calling my CSS animation with jQuery.  Basically, if the value of the input is nothing, I want the form to wobble (implying something is wrong).  I tried using `.addClass`, but it still doesn't work.

HTML

```
<form id="form">
     <input type="text" id="fld"/>
     <button id="btn">Get</button> 
</form>
```

CSS

```
form {
display: block;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 340px;
padding: 55px 0 0 0;
-webkit-transition: webkit-transform .75s ease-in-out;
}

.someAnimation {
-webkit-animation: errorAlert .75s ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes errorAlert {

0%{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
}

25%{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
}


50%{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(-20px);
}

75%{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(20px);
}

100%{
    -webkit-transform:translateX(0px);
}


}
```

jQuery

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
            if($('#fld').val() == null || $('#fld').val() == ""){
                $('#form').addClass('.someAnimation');
            }
       });
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

your using `.someAnimation` in jquery `addClass` function you should use it without `DOT`

you should use

```
  $('#form').addClass('someAnimation');
```

Comment: Yeah, I make that mistake a lot.  Fixed it, still isn't working.  It works, but moves so fast and jerky.

Comment: Is there a way to make it slower? or more smooth?

Answer (score 0):

Replace the  **.someAnimation** with **someAnimation** . Then ,

Make sure that your **if()** condition is **true** and Try using the **trim()** like ,

```
$('#btn').on('click', function(){
        if($.trim($('#fld').val()) == null || $.trim($('#fld').val()) == "")           
             alert("Condition works");
             $('#form').addClass('someAnimation');
        }
});
```

But not sure this works in your scenario .